# When I run guide in matlab it opens a blank all gray window. Whats going on?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

When I run guide in Matlab, the window that opens is completely grayed out with a title "GUIDE quick start". I am running R2012b in Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. Has anyone else run into this problem?

UPDATE 1

So I just discovered that if I press enter on that first blank grey window then it opens the Layout Editor window and everything seems to be fine. So I am guessing that on that first screen there is just an OK button (which I cannot see) so when I press enter it is like clicking on the OK button.

UPDATE 2

I built a quick GUI and there are issues. I can create axes and buttons and sliders on the layout tool. However, when I run the GUI tool it only displays the axes, the buttons, sliders are not there.

Comment: Whats the output of: `version -java` (run inside MATLAB)? I've seen problems trying to use Java 7 on Windows (using `MATLAB_JAVA` environment variable). The bundled version should be Java 6

Comment: @amro Java 1.7.0_15-b03 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode

Comment: downgrade to Java 1.6

Comment: Thank you @Amro! That was it! I am curious to see if this will also fix some issues with pcolor plots where the axis text information was missing or heavily smudged. I have a feeling it will fix that too. By the way, you should probably place it as an answer so I can give you proper credit?

Comment: nope that didn't fix the issue with axis text being unreadable... its still there, but thats a minor thing I guess.

Comment: similar question: [Cannot launch MATLAB guis (GUIDE) on scientific linux with jre 1.7.0_05](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11624154/97160)

Comment: I'm afraid I cant help with the pcolor issue. I'm actually running on WinXP, and I'm not seeing a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe some things in MATLAB are not yet compatible with Java 7, so stick with Java 6 for the moment.

In any case, you can have both versions installed at the same time, just instruct MATLAB to use the correct version by setting the `$MATLAB_JAVA` environment variable.

You can then verify which version is being used by issuing the command:

```
>> version -java
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Ubuntu, got solved by skipping Unity and starting the session with "classic gnome" instead.