# MATLAB GUIDE window appears empty and without controls

Tags: java, matlab, ubuntu, matlab-guide

I'm running MATLAB 2013b on Ubuntu, and I'm having many problems with the display of windows. For instance, when I try to start GUIDE (typing "guide" at the command prompt), I get just an empty rectangle.

Looks like some kind of incompatibility between MATLAB, Ubuntu and Java, but I'm not sure about how to proceed... any ideas?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114951/

Answer (score 0):

... well, just in case somebody comes across the same problem, I'll leave my answer: it's just a question of giving up Unity in Ubuntu and start the session with the "classical gnome desktop (no effects)" option.